# ODI-5001 Cannot Killing session in ODI

Tags: oracle, session

I need to kill session a session in ODI but it tell :

**ODI-5001: Session DIMENSI account_Physical_SESS (8991) could not be stopped by Agent Internal: Session run on an Internal agent cannot be stopped from another process.**

when I see & try the code it execute this and takes long time also not stopped :

**DROP TABLE I$_Customer ;**

is there any solution instead of restart the DB.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using LKM to import the data from different DB then the query will stuck in the source DB it self you can directly drop the I$ table and mark the step as failed and restart the job from create I$ step, We are using same process in our project and it is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

If the session seems to be hung than you can open the Session-level node (the top node) and set the Status to 'Error'

After a moment or two the agent will drop the session and the icon will change from the 'running' icon to the 'error' icon.

Answer (score 0):

This error means the session was started using Local Agent. You started the session from the ODI Studio and this ODI Studio is a client which actually executes a query. It is an Internal Agent.

Only a session being executing on external agent could be fully managed from the Operator window. Others could be terminated only from ODI Studio which has started them.

There are two possibilities:

1. Go to the workstation which executes the session (which started the session) and try to stop session from there. If ODI Studio hang you may kill the its process. (Probable after that it would be necessary to do Clean Stale Sessions)
2. It is also possible to do `alter system kill session 'sid,serial' immediate` from DB side.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database, there is a fair chance that the session will continue at database level, even as Operator will tell you that is has failed. In that case you will have to kill the database session as well.

It looks like you had that issue before, because a hang of a drop table usually means another process is accessing that table.

In addition to Naeel's post (also assuming Oracle): the action field in v$sql can help you find the session/session retry run/step of the ODI process that started the database process. If all this sounds weird to you ask you dba.